# Get data from http request in Angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, express, httprequest, angular5

I am trying to build a little server monitor/control console with nodejs, expressjs and Angular 5. To determine whether the apache service is running on the remote server I built a backend script, that tries to get get a script from the server I want to control. The problem is, that I do not know how to get the data a `http.get` from angular returns. In the example below I try to set the variable `this.apacheRunning` to the response of the `http.get` requests. Would be thankful for any help!

```
getApacheRunning(): Observable<String>{

    this.apacheRunning = this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/ison").subscribe(result => this.apacheRunning = result,(err) => console.log(err), ()=> console.log("done"));
    console.log(this.result);

    if(this.apacheRunning == "true"){
      console.log(this.apacheRunning + "DEBUG2");
      return of("true");
    }else{
      console.log(this.apacheRunning + "DEBUG1");
      return of("false")
    }



}
```

The code is available on gitHub under: https://github.com/Clemens-Dautermann

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to actually subscribe in your method. Rather you want to return the observable result from http request.

If you want to log a debug to see what the result is, you can chain a `do` operation on your observable chain.

If you want to do processing on the result to transform it, you can use the `map` operator on your observable chain.

If you want to handle errors that result from not being able to talk to the server, you can use the `catch` operator and return an appropriate result or do some other processing.

```js
getApacheRunning(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/ison')
        .do(res => console.log('apacheRunning ', res))
        .map(res => (res === 'true').toString())
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Failed to determine if Apache is running', err);
            return Observable.of('false');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an **Async** request then you need to catch the response value in the response Callback take a look to this example:

```
this.repository().subscribe(result =>{
   this.apacheRunning = result;
});

repository(){
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/ison")
    .map(res => { 
        return res.json().map(item => { 
           return item;
     });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your `apacheRunning` conditions in subscribe loop.

Modify your code as follows :

```
getApacheRunning(): Observable<String>{

  this.apacheRunning = this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/ison").subscribe(result => {
    this.apacheRunning = result
    if(this.apacheRunning == "true"){
     console.log(this.apacheRunning + "DEBUG2");
     return of("true");
    }else{
      console.log(this.apacheRunning + "DEBUG1");
      return of("false")
    }
    console.log(result);
  },(err) => console.log(err), () => console.log("done"));
}
```